# mockito refEq дурацкий matcher почему так работает?

Tags: java, mockito

```
static class A{
    public Integer f1;
    private Double f2;

    public void setF2(Double f2) {
        this.f2 = f2;
    }
}
```

вот такой тест успешно завершается:

```
A a = new A();
a.setF2(1.2d);
a.f1 = 1;
A a2 = new A();
a2.setF2(1.3d);
a2.f1 = 1;
assertEquals(eq(a), refEq(a2));
```

Почему этот матчер не сравнивает значения полей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы почитайте Javadoc к методам `eq` и `refEq` и увидите, что для непримитивных типов они возвращают null.
Ну и в итоге `assertEquals(null,null)` будет `true`.

Comment: я читал javadoc для этих матчеров, там ничего такого не написано. Сказано лишь, что сравнивает поля и точка

Comment: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Matchers.html#eq(T)
http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Matchers.html#refEq(T, java.lang.String...)
Там ясно написано:

Returns:
null.

Comment: Вообще, такое ощущение, что вы не совсем поняли, что такое матчеры и когда их нужно использовать.

Comment: я только вчера узнал о мохито. Методы которые работают только внутри verify и asserts, и почему-то почти всегда возращают null

Comment: Почитайте примеры, на хабре должны быть статьи. 
Если в двух словах - assert - это сравнение чего-то с чем-то. Не нужно туда передавать матчеры. 
verify - это метод для проверки, случился ли (и сколько раз) вызов определенного метода в замоченом объекте.
Матчеры используются в том же verify(), для того, чтобы обозначить, например, что не важны аргументы метода, а сам факт его вызова.

Comment: но ведь иногда удобно в assert поместить матчер, что же с собой делать в этом случае?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24921/discussion-between-voipp-and-zzashpaupat).

Comment: @voipp я в чат вам написал, жду ответа